# Splitting Movement and Power Tokens

Tags: game-of-thrones

When resolving a march order, you can split the movement of your troops into several adjacent territories, but only one of those territories may contain units of another house. Does moving into an area containing another house's power token (but none of the house's combat units) count as an act of aggression precluding you from attacking from the same territory?

For example, can Baratheon use one footman in Harrenhal to attack Lannister's footman in Stoney Sept and the other to take Blackwater, which is controlled by Lannister's power token?[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed. From page 13 in the rulebook:

> If marching units enter an area containing one or more enemy units, a combat ensues (only one combat, however, may be initiated for each March Order).

So there's only a problem if you try to initiate two battles with the same marching order (which you're not permitted to do. But as described on page 24 in the rulebook:

> A Power token on the game board is returned to the Power Pool only after an opponent takes control of its area. Marching into an area containing only an opponent’s Power token (i.e., no enemy units are present) does not result in combat, and the Power token is simply discarded to the Power Pool.

No combat occurs in this instance, therefore it is an allowed action.

Answer (score 1):

The power token is not counted as an opposing force, so yes it is allowed.
For clarity of game flow, move the non-contesting pieces first, and the attacking units last.
Also be careful that unit population caps are correct.